# "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" in my Runnable class, why?

Tags: java, sockets, socketexception

I have this code for "Server" in socket programming application, and I have this Exception `java.net.SocketException` in line 26 of the following code in this line of code:

```
while((line=bReader.readLine())!=null){
```

What is the problem causing this exception?

Server:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
public class Server implements Runnable{
    final public int PORT=1212;
    private Socket client;
    private ServerSocket server;
    private BufferedReader bReader;
    private PrintWriter pWriter;
    public void run(){
        try {
            System.out.println("Start server ...");
            server=new ServerSocket(PORT);
            while(true){
                System.out.println("Start listening on PORT "+PORT+" ...");
                client=server.accept();
                System.out.println("Connection with client["+client.getInetAddress().getHostName()+"]");
                bReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                pWriter=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream())),true);
                    String line="";
                    while((line=bReader.readLine())!=null){
                        RecoginzeMessage(line);
                    }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                client.close();
            //  server.close();
                bReader.close();
                pWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    public void RecoginzeMessage(String msg){
        String msg_params[]=msg.split(":");
        switch(Integer.parseInt(msg_params[0])){
        case 0:// Authetication process 
            System.out.println("Authentication new client");
            AuthenticateUser(msg_params[1],msg_params[2]);
            break;
        }
    }
    public void AuthenticateUser(String username, String password){
        if(username.equals("adham")&&password.equals("adham")){
            pWriter.println("1");
            pWriter.flush();
        }
        else{
            pWriter.println("0");
            pWriter.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

and this code for "client" ..

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Client implements Runnable {
    public final String SERVER_IP="127.0.0.1";
    public final int PORT=1212;
    private Socket client;
    private BufferedReader bReader;
    private PrintWriter pWriter;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    public Client(){
        if(client==null)
            try {
                client=new Socket(SERVER_IP,PORT);
                bReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                pWriter=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream())),true);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }
    public void run(){

            System.out.print("Enter username: ");
            String username=sc.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter password: ");
            String password=sc.nextLine();

            if(login(username,password)){
                System.out.print(">logged in successfuly");             
            }else{
                System.out.print(">Inavlied username or password");                             
            }

    }
    private boolean login(String username, String password){
        try{
            pWriter.println("0:"+username+":"+password);
            pWriter.flush();
            while(true){
                String line="";
                while((line=bReader.readLine())!=null){
                    if(line.equals("1"))
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }

            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: The class to run Client thread

```
public class RunClient {    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Client cThread=new Client();
        cThread.run();
    }
}
```

Edit: The class to run Server thread

```
public class RunServer {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Server sThread=new Server();
        sThread.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: To whom voted it down and to be closed, I have edited the question. Before you do that you cam show what is your problem in the question here in comments !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client seems to be executed by a thread, but just implementing `Runnable` is not correct, you need to create a `Thread` and pass the `Runnable`to it. The client not executes indefinitely, so the client **finishes** and **closes** implicitly (the JVM) the socket and the Server get this exception to indicate that (client closes the socket).

Comment: "you need to create a Thread and pass the Runnable to it" , what do you mean ? can you show an example plz ?

Comment: Being class `A` a `Runnable`object, try `new Thread(new A()).run()`.

Comment: Running the client and server within a thread not solves the problem as if the `run()`method finishes, the thread itself finishes and the application finishes. Must think about what should do the client and until when and set the "finish" condition. The server should be aware of this exception as the client would finish at any time. Set a "finish" command or message from the client to the server if desired.

Comment: I don't want to close the connection, I want it to be open to send more messages , do I need to open the connection each time I want to send a message ?, Can I use loop that read and write , and stop in some command such as 'stop' ?

Comment: You can close the connection and reopen each time want to send a message, but then the server can not associate the messages from the same client -> add some data to the messages to indicate the client id. The other way is to maintain the connection opened to send all messages you need, but you need to stay in the 'run()' method of the client, waiting for the user to entry some data or another event; if not, the `run()` method finishes and the client application. Think about what your client should do, send some messages and finish or perform some interactive dialog with the user?

Comment: "client id" is a good idea, but how can the server maintain more than one client. as I know .accept() method override the previous client socket , right ? . So can I use an array-for example- to associate each socket with client Id, and each time the server want to communicate, it search about client id in the array and get it's socket and start connection, is that true ?

Comment: In order to manage several clients simultaneously (each one with its own socekt) in the server, must create a thread after `accept()` to attend this client and continue listening for clients in a while loop. Like `while(finish condition) { Socket client = server.accept(); new Worker(client).start();}` The `Worker` class must be `Runnable` and process the messages from a client.

Comment: I want to make the server to perform as a proxy(manager) to handle several clients, and to get the message from one client and send it to the required another client, as the sender send a message with the id of the receiver, how can I know the required client running on different thread, how can I get the socket of the associate client that the id represents it ? is ti clear ? :)

Comment: It's clear, but this should be on another question as it's out of scope of the current one. Try to use shared structures and use only one thread to read and write to all the clients, maintain the client sockets in a list and perform a loop to read from all clients and write to desired ones and wait some milliseconds after starting again.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid `SocketException` try out to add `wait()` or similar something as the last statement in `run()` method in the client app.